# Retrieving google photos with IONIC 3 with google photos API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am working on an IONIC application.
In this app the user will be able to get photos from his **google photos** account and do some design manipulations on the image he selected.

So for that I want to use the [google photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/)

I did not find any example on how to accomplish this in IONIC.

So I am looking for some sample code or guid on how to get this done.

=======================================================

## UPDATE

I tried to do it like this:

Login to google with: `cordova-plugin-googleplus`

And request the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary`
scope

Here is the code:

```js
//Here we do a login.
this.gplus.login({
   'webClientId': '***********',
   'offline': true,
   'scopes': 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary'
}).then((res) => {
   //after login we try to get the google photos albums
   this.http.get('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums', {
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Json,
      params:{
         accessToken: res.accessToken,
         pageSize: 50,          
      }
   }).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('<--- google images res: ', res);
   },err=>{
      console.log('<--- google images err: ', err);
   });
});
```

Now I get an error 'Expected OAuth 2 access token'

Here is the full error description:

```
Request is missing required authentication credential. 
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. 
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

==========================================================

## UPDATE 2

So after some research I am trying to get the OAuth 2 access token like this:

```js
//Here we do a login.
this.gplus.login({
   'webClientId': '***********',
   'offline': true,
   'scopes': 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary'
}).then((res) => {
   //after login we need to get the OAuth 2 access
   //I think like this:
   this.http.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', {
      code: res.serverAuthCode,
      client_id: '*****************',
      client_secret: '*************',
      redirect_url: '***************',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
   },{
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Json
   }).subscribe(res=>{
      //after we got the OAuth 2 access, we try to get the google photos albums
      let myHeaders= new Headers();
      myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.http.get('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums', {
         responseType: ResponseContentType.Json,
         params:{
            pageSize: 50,    
            accessToken: {'bearer': res['_body'].access_token},
          },
          headers: myHeaders
        }).subscribe(res=>{
          console.log('<--- google images res: ', res);
        },err=>{
          console.log('<--- google images err: ', err);
        })
   },err=>{
      ......
   })
  }  
}), err => {
   .....
});
```

But still getting the same error:

```
Request is missing required authentication credential. 
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. 
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

So now the question is how do is get an **OAuth 2 access token** ?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. But the way i am fetching something is by using refresh token, which i got from the oauth playground. So in the API body i pass, grant_type, client_id, client_secret and refresh_token. This returns an access token with the correct scopes, but when i try to use the token to call the albums API from google photos API, it fails saying, unauthenticated. Were you able to solve this issue?